# Android app Feed view is stuck at "Earlier this month"

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

After using the app (version 1.0.51) successfully for some time on my Samsung Galaxy S3, the Feed view has stopped working. When I navigate to Feed, it always shows the same items it was showing me on October 1st. Refreshing via pull-down doesn't change this; closing and reopening the app doesn't change it; pressing Back a bunch of times doesn't change it; power-cycling my device doesn't change it. The next obvious step in debugging would be to reinstall it, but I'd rather post here so that the underlying bug can be fixed.

Comment: This issue fixed itself a little while ago, perhaps on November first? I don't know exactly when, since with the app broken I wasn't turning it on very often.